# What/when does a call to the jQuery AJAX method return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, slickgrid

A little background:

I am trying to implement and AJAX powered SlickGrid.  There isn't much documentation so I used [this example as a base](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html).

In this example there is the following code that hits the desired web service to get the data:

```
req = $.jsonp({
                    url: url,
                    callbackParameter: "callback",
                    cache: true, // Digg doesn't accept the autogenerated cachebuster param
                    success: onSuccess,
                    error: function(){
                        onError(fromPage, toPage)
                    }
                    });
                req.fromPage = fromPage;
                req.toPage = toPage;
```

[I'm not exactly sure what jsonp does](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) but from what i've read it appears to be very similar to the ajax method in jQuery except it returns json and allows cross domain requests.  The webservice that I happen to be calling only returns XML so I changed this chunk of code to:

```
req = $.ajax({
                url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: xmlData,
                complete: onSuccess,
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("error: " + xhr.statusText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                },
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
            });
            req.fromPage = fromPage;
        req.toPage = toPage;
```

My issue is that my page errors out at `req.fromPage = fromPage;` because `req` is null.

Am I wrong to think that I can just replace my jsonp call with a call to the ajax method?  Is req just not set because my ajax call hasn't finished by the time that code is executed?    How can I get around either of these issues?

If I comment out the last two lines and hard-code those values elsewhere everything runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I wrong to think that I can just replace my jsonp call with a call to the ajax method?

No, that should work just fine.

> Is req just not set because my ajax call hasn't finished by the time that code is executed?

Yes, that is correct.

The ajax methods starts the request and returns immediately. If you want to do something after the response has arrived you should do that in the `success` event handler.

You might actually want to use the `success` event instead of the `complete` event, as the `complete` event happens even if there is an error.

You *could* specify `async: false,` in your settings to make the ajax call wait for the response, but that means that the browser freezes while it's waiting.

Comment: Ok good to know.  Out of curiosity, why did the jsonp method not require that values for req be set in the onSuccess function?  Does this not return immediately like ajax does?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: Both methods are asynchronous, it's not even possible to make a synchronous JSONP call. You are getting the `req` object from the return value of the call, which may differ between the methods. Neither method can return the result of the request, so you shouldn't use the return value for your result anyway.

Comment: I understand that the `jsonp` call not returning the results immidiately, but it must be returning SOMETHING immediately if it doesn't throw the same error, correct?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: It's evidently returning some kind of object, but that is not really important. You shouldn't have used the return value from that method for your result in the first place. Just create a new object, so you know what it contains: `var req = {};`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa) [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541440/what-when-does-a-call-to-the-jquery-ajax-method-return/6541501#6541501), `$.ajax()` works asynchronically. Thus, you have to specify a *callback* that will be called when the request has returned a response, rather than to just use whatever `$.ajax()` returns.

There are a couple of different callback methods you can specify:

- `complete` - runs when you recieve a response, regardless of its status.
- `success` - runs when you recieve a response with a successful status code (usually 200).
- `error` - runs when you recieve a response with an error code (for example 404 or 500).

To do something with the response body after a successful request, you should do something like

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(body) {
        alert('This is the method body:' + body);
    }
});
```

Read up in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on the different methods to see what more parameters you can use.